# get data from table using multiple IDs from another table using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have assessment with assessment id . the assessment read questions from multiple question bank categories (specific number of questions randomly from each category)

I need to make query to collect the questions from the different categories using php and mysql. i have tried that:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`  WHERE `category_id` IN (SELECT   `category_id` FROM `assessment_category` WHERE `assessment_id`= $id   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number)";
```

But it gives my error server version doesn't support in with limit.

I also used inner join

```
$query ="SELECT *   FROM questions AS v INNER JOIN (SELECT category_id FROM assessment_category WHERE assessment_id = $id ) as v2  ON v.category_id = v2.category_id  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number";
```

But also doesn't work. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $query = "select * from assessment_category where assessment_id = $id ";
    foreach($cats as $cat){
        //$cat_id = $cat['category_id'];
        //$number = $cat['number_of_questions'];
        //$query = "select * from questions where category_id IN (select category_id from assessment_category where assessment_id = $id   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number) ";
        //$query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`  WHERE `category_id` IN (SELECT `category_id` FROM `assessment_category` WHERE `assessment_id`= $id   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number)";

    //}
 }

Comment: //$query = "SELECT * FROM questions AS v INNER JOIN (SELECT category_id FROM assessment_category WHERE assessment_id= $id  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number)as v2 ON v.category_id = v2.category_id";

Comment: $query ="SELECT *
                            FROM questions AS v
                            INNER JOIN
                                 (SELECT category_id FROM assessment_category WHERE assessment_id = $id ) as v2
                              ON v.category_id = v2.category_id 
                            ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number
                          "; 
        $questions = $psychometric->selectData($query, $con);

Comment: This is unreadable, put the code in the question and format it so that it is easy to read.

Comment: ok look at this: $query = "select * from questions where category_id IN (select category_id from assessment_category where assessment_id = $id   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number) ";

Comment: what error showing ?

Comment: @jothi This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: mysql dose not support limit in subquery in some versions

Comment: SELECT * FROM questions AS v INNER JOIN (SELECT category_id FROM assessment_category WHERE assessment_id = 21 ) as v2 ON v2.category_id = v.category_id ORDER BY RAND()
but this give me all the questions , i need specific number form each one

Comment: TRY THIS   $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`  WHERE `category_id` 
     IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT   `category_id` FROM `assessment_category` WHERE `assessment_id`= $id   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number))";

Comment: @jothi Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @hany try this $query = "SELECT * FROM `questions`  WHERE `category_id` 
     IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT   `category_id` FROM `assessment_category` WHERE `assessment_id`= $id   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,$number) as new_alias)";

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$cats // data for categories
$query2 = "";
$numItems = count($cats);
$i = 0;
foreach($cats as $cat){
    $cat_id = $cat['category_id'];
    $number = $cat['number_of_questions'];
      if(++$i === $numItems) {
            $query2 .= " (SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE category_id = $cat_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $number)";
      }else{
            $query2 .= "(SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE category_id = $cat_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $number)
                UNION ALL ";
      }                          
    $questions // execute your query;
}
```

Thanks for all